# Getting the response text from a getJson call

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I'm trying to implement a function that will do something based off of the response text given by a certain ajax call. But I can't access the response text field. Here is my code:

```
               var response = $.getJSON('/add_participant',{
                email : uemail,
                password : upassword
               })
```

and I've tried to access it this way:

```
response.responseText
```

But when I log it out to the console, it says it's undefined.

I think it has something to do with the ajax call needing to resolve first, before I access the response text. That's because if I save it to a global variable, when I pull up the webpage and use the inspection tools, I am able to access the responseText in that way.

How can I get that response text during my function? Is there a way I can have the script wait for it to resolve or whatever?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$.getJSON` is well documented. You are using it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since this gets executed asynchronously, you need to handle it in `.done` callback. Here is the sample code.

```
var response = null; // assign to [] if you think you will receive an array
$.getJSON('/add_participant',{
  email : uemail,
  password : upassword
}).done(function (data) {
  response = data;
  console.log('response: ', data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I figured out what was wrong with my code, and it was actually a problem with the python code I was calling. I'm setting up my website with the Flask library in Python, and I was using the ajax call to use a python function in the back end and get the output it returned. The problem was that when I returned the output in the python function, I was returning a string, just like this:

```
return ("It worked!")
```

The rest of the function was still operating and doing the things I wanted it to do, and I could still check out the response when I used the inspection tools. But the returned value was in the incorrect format. It seems that this resulted in something along the lines of the Javascript code on the front end not getting the message from Python that the Python function had finished. And for that reason, nothing in the ***.done(function (data) { } )*** block would get executed.

To fix this, I had to instead return a jsonified dictionary. jsonify is a function from the flask library. Here's how it should look:

```
return(jsonify({'result': 'It worked!'}))
```

And then if you want to access that data back in the javascript, access the result property of the data object inside the 
 ***.done(function (data) { } )*** block. For me, it looked like this:

```
var response = $.getJSON('/add_participant',{
                email : uemail,
                password : upassword
               }).done(function (data) {
                if (data.result ='It Worked!'){
                    console.log("It worked!!");
                    // Do whatever else you wanted

                }
                else{
                    console.log("It didn't work.");
                    // Do something else
                }


                })
```